# Reading from the header of a bmp file

Tags: c, pointers, struct, bmp

I am writing a program to read a bmp header. I've written some code that was working when it was all in `main`. How to implement this code as a function of its own and then implementing it onto main?

Here is the whole code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdin.h> 

struct bmp_header { 
    uint16_t type; 
    uint32_t size; 
    uint16_t reserved1;     
    uint16_t reserved2;    
    uint32_t offset;        
    uint32_t dib_size;  
    uint32_t width;         
    uint32_t height;        
    uint16_t planes;       
    uint16_t bpp;            
    uint32_t compression;    
    uint32_t image_size;    
    uint32_t x_ppm;         
    uint32_t y_ppm;          
    uint32_t num_colors;     
    uint32_t important_colors; 
}; 


void read_bmp(FILE *BMPFile,struct bmp_header* Header) {  
    fread(&(Header->type), 2, 1, BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->size),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->reserved1),2,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->reserverd2),2,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->offset),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->dib_size),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->width),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->height),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->planes),2,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->bpp),2,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->compression),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->image_size),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->x_ppm),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->y_pp),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->num_colors),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&(Header->important_colors),4,1,BMPFile); 
} 

int main() { 
    FILE *BMPFile = fopen("image.bmp","rb"); 
    if(BMPFile == NULL) 
    { 
        return; 
    } 

    struct bmp_header* Header; 
    read_bmp(BMPFile,Header); 
    fclose(BMPFile); 

    return 0; 
}
```

The relevant parts of the version of the program with all reading action in `main`, that worked as expected, is reported below

```
int main( void )
{
    FILE *BMPFile = fopen ("lenna.bmp", "rb");

    if (BMPFile == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    struct bmp_header Header;

    memset(&Header, 0, sizeof(Header));

    fread(&Header.type, 2, 1, BMPFile);
    fread(&Header.size),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.reserved1),2,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.reserverd2),2,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.offset),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.dib_size),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.width),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.height),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.planes),2,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.bpp),2,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.compression),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.image_size),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.x_ppm),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.y_pp),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.num_colors),4,1,BMPFile); 
    fread(&Header.important_colors),4,1,BMPFile);

    /* Header fields print section */
    /* ...                         */
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you have working code, and that you want your working code to look more like what you posted (but working)? If so, could you post the working code?

Edit: struct bmp_header is a pointer, but it's never given any memory to work with. So that's *a* problem.

Comment: In the working function `bmp_header` was defined in the stack and then `memset`d to 0 and its fields' addresses passed directly to fread. Now you create a pointer, but you don't allocate the memory to point to.

Comment: You removed the page with the original code. Without it the question is incomplete and my answer doesn't make sense. I'm suggesting an edit inserting the part I copied yesterday in my answer from your source.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a working code stops working, it is useful to focus on the changes between the two versions of the code. So, why does your original code work correctly? It looks like this:

```
int main( void )
{
    FILE *BMPFile = fopen ("lenna.bmp", "rb");

    if (BMPFile == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    struct bmp_header Header;

    memset(&Header, 0, sizeof(Header));

    fread(&Header.type, 2, 1, BMPFile);
    ...
}
```

1. You declare `Header`, of type `struct bmp_header`, in main's stack (as local variable). **In this way the structure will be for sure allocated during all program's lifetime**.
2. You `memset` it to 0
3. You pass `Header`'s fields addresses directly to `fread`

---

In the new version of the program you have a function defined as

```
void read_bmp(FILE *BMPFile,struct bmp_header* Header);
```

so you need a pointer to `struct bmp_header` to be passed to it. For this reason you declare

struct bmp_header* Header;

and call `read_bmp(BMPFile,Header);`.

What is the different with the working version? Well, **the pointer**! Declaring a pointer you say to the compiler that it contains an address, in this case the address of the structure required by `read_bmp()`.

But you **never** say to the compiler what the address is, so that `fread`s within `read_bmp()` will write to random location causing a segmentation fault.

---

### What to do

You need to pass to `read_bmp()` a *valid* `struct bmp_header` address, and you have **two options**.

1. You can allocate `Header` in the stack like you did before, and pass its address to  `read_bmp()`, through `&` operator. It should have been your first attempt, since it was really similar to your working solution.

```
    struct bmp_header Header;

    read_bmp(BMPFile, &Header);
```

2. You can declare `Header` as a pointer, but you will need to dynamically allocate its memory through `malloc`:

```
    struct bmp_header * Header = malloc(sizeof(struct bmp_header));

    read_bmp(BMPFile, Header);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create struct bmp_header* type function. Next create struct bmp_header pointer in your function & allocate memory (header size == 54B) for returned reference.

Comment: Although the file uses a 54 byte header, `struct bmp_header` does not certainly contain 54 bytes due to padding.  Better to use `sizeof(struct bmp_header)` than hard-code 54.